# If else statements in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have an if else condition I want to implement in clojure... But stuck with not knowing how to do for multiple if's

My code is like

```
{
if(x=a)
{
you return sol1
} else
{
sol 3
}
and if(x=b)
{
return sol2
}
else
{
sol 3-same as first cond
}
}
```

This is some what example for finding greatest integer among 3. 
How do i do it in clojure?

Comment: Can you explain what behavior you are trying to encode here?  Sometimes you use `sol` as a value to return, sometimes not, and not clear what you are trying to use `and` for.

Comment: It's a value to return when the first fails.

Comment: Are you asking for a 3-way conditional? You can use `cond`.

Comment: @joey: That doesn't help at all; please explain the desired behavior.

Comment: @ScottHunter I actually have a value. I have to check the unit of the value, if the unit is cm I have to convert it to mm. If it is in lb have to convert it to oz. else return the value itself.

Comment: @Lee Like above mentioned comment

Comment: So you do have three cases? How are the units represented?

Comment: @joey, did you look at `cond` (i.e., https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond)?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I have seen cond function and it worked!!

Comment: @joey check out https://clojuredocs.org/ it's really awesome.  Great way to discover new ways to do stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, take your pick of the following. They all have the same behavior.

```
(if (= x a)
  sol1
  (if (= x b)
    sol2
    sol3))
```

or

```
(cond
  (= x a) sol1
  (= x b) sol2
  :else   sol3)
```

or

```
(condp = x
  a sol1
  b sol2
  sol3)
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks :) I have just seen cond function